# Angular issues updating the view / retrieving promise value after it's fulfilled

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I have the following label on my view:

```
<label id="error" class="error">{{ login.error }}</label>
```

With the following route / controller setup (snippet)

```
    $routeProvider.
        when('/login',
        {
            controller  : 'LoginController',
            controllerAs: 'login',
            templateUrl : 'app/views/auth/login.html'
        }).
```

Herewith some of the controller code:

```
function LoginController(user, auth, $location)
{
    var self = this;

    self.error = 'blah'; // works

    function handleRequest(res)
    {
        if (typeof res != 'undefined')
        {
            var token = res.data ? res.data.token : null;

            if (token && auth.isAuthed())
                $location.path('/layout');

            if (res.status == 401)
            {
                return { status:res.status, statusText:res.statusText, error:res.data.error }
            }
        }
    }

    self.login = function(form)
    {
        self.error = 'blah'; // doesn't work

        if(form.validate())
        {
            user.login(self.username, self.password)
                .then(handleRequest, handleRequest)
        }
    }
```

I cannot get the login.error value to update within the method.
I've also tried $scope with $apply to no avail.

**The next issue is the**

user.login(self.username, self.password)
    .then(handleRequest, handleRequest)

promise, in the handleRequest method, I return the following:

return { status:res.status, statusText:res.statusText, error:res.data.error }

How on earth do I get that value from the fulfilled promise?

If I output the result to the console, I get the following:

[image: promise]

I tried messing around with another .then etc. to no avail.

**EDIT:**

This seems to work in retrieving the promise value:

```
self.login = function(form)
    {
        self.error = 'blah'; // doesn't work

        if(form.validate())
        {
            var login = user.login(self.username, self.password)
                            .then(handleRequest, handleRequest)

            login.then(function(response)
            {
                console.log(response);
            });
        }
    }
```

I just need to figure out how to display in on the view from the method now.

Comment: Did you tried using `$scope.error` instead `self.error`.

Comment: Injecting $scope and setting $scope.error doesn't seem to work at all

Answer (score 0):

I eventually found that a validation package that I was using added a display:none style if you have a class attribute named error on the label.

Therefore the value was always updating but was never displaying :/